# mousePressed function seems to press more than once

Tags: java, mouse, processing

I'm new to the [Processing programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) and currently trying to make a turned based game with my university group. However I have a problem with the function in Processing called mousePressed. The problem seems to be that the mousePressed function is done more than once, even if I only press the mouse once. I'm probably wrong about this, but any help would be nice.

I have 5 buttons, if I click one of them it adds X amount players in my ArrayList, and after that it should continue to the first player turn, over to the dice, which can be rolled by clicking the screen. However when I click my add player button, it also roll the dice, but I want the player to choice amount players, and then click on the screen again to roll the dice.

The code:

```
  //this is my "if" the player choose to have two players, the first player turns begin

  if(player.get(0) == 1){
        fill(255);
        text("First player turn", width/2, height/5);
        noLoop();

        dice.display();
        dice.mouseRoll();


 // here you have my dice roll function
  void mouseRoll(){                    
    if(mousePressed==true){
      dice.roll(1,4);  // just a random between the two number
        noLoop();
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger with breakpoints or using print statements to debug? It should be pretty easy to find out for certain if the mouse event is triggering multiple times.

Comment: I dont think is a bug, have tried to do println, and it shows it sometimes 3-7 times the event occur.

Comment: Your example code doesn't contain any sort of mouse listener, which makes it hard to tell how you are receiving click events. Some libraries will send click information every time the UI loop cycles. In these cases you have to explicitly track the mouse's state, which is pretty lame.

Comment: There seems to be some disagreement about whether the `java` tag is appropriate here. I'm throwing this to the Java experts. A suggested edit was submitted replacing the `java` tag with `processing`. It was about to be rejected as "too minor" (http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3234978). I approved it but added back the `java` tag because Processing is essentially a dialect of Java, and the `processing` tag has very few followers (one thousandth as many as `java`) and would make the question unlikely to get much attention.

Comment: The editor re-suggested the edit removing the `java` tag, saying that it was confusing people (http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3235078). I edited the question to clarify that it's about a Java-based language rather than pure Java. The question is, do Java experts agree that the `java` tag belongs in a question about Processing?

Comment: Although Processing is a dialect of java, the specific question addresses Processing specific methods (void mousePressed()) and fields(boolean mousePressed). It depends though about the tag... Would a swt/swing question not have the java tag just because it would have toolkit specific methods and fields?

Answer (score 7):

Obviously the code you have here is in your draw() loop. That loops over 25 times (or more) a second and each one of those times you are checking if the mouse is pressed. Of course its going to trigger more than once unless you are really really fast.

The proper way to do this is not with that if statement but with [void mousePressed()](http://processing.org/reference/mousePressed_.html), which triggers once every time you click!

Edit:
A sample according to your comment:

> is it possible to do so that the first button is pressed to get player
>   and then roll the dice, so it dont do everything in one click

In order to do that you need to add a boolean which signifies if the player has been selected. If the player has been selected then roll the dice, otherwise select a player! (or switch turns?)

```
boolean playerSelected = false;
void mousePressed() {
  if(!playerSelected) {
    // select a player here or switch turns
    fill(255);
    text("First player turn", width/2, height/5);
    playerSelected = true;
  }
  else { 
    dice.display();
    dice.roll(1,4);
    playerSelected = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that mousePressed in not a function. mousePressed() is.

Comment: It still not seem to work even if I do it with void mousePressed(), is it possible to do so that the first button is pressed to get player and then roll the dice, so it dont do everything in one click.

Comment: You don't give us much of your code to actually give a solution, but I edited my post to give you an idea...